# error catastrophic failure installshield 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, installshield-le

I am using installshield LE 2012 for visual studio to create a installable file for my problem written in VB on .NET.

While my problem requires a third party driver to be installed first. So I added to run it as a custom action during installation "before first dialog".

However, every time I tried to install it, it shows the "error: catastrophic failure", which I have no idea what it means. Does it mean the process of installing the driver take too much time? or there is any resource collision problem between these two?

How to solve this problem? I really needs some help.

The OS I am using is Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: What's catastrophic is the quality of the error reporting.  The error code is E_UNEXPECTED, it doesn't mean anything more than "oops, I didn't expect that to go wrong".  You'll need help from InstallShield if the install log file doesn't give hints.

Comment: where can I find the log file? I can only see the build log files.

Comment: His installer is calling an out of process custom action to install a third party driver.  Why would you need help from InstallShield???

Answer (score 0):

You need to get support from your third party driver vendor.  Your custom action is calling out of process code that InstallShield has no control over.  We don't know what your driver vendor, name and version is or how you are calling it so there's nothing we can do to help you here.

FWIW, InstallShield and Windows Installer has support for using DIFx to install drivers based on .INF files.  But this isn't supported in the crippled InstallShield Limited Edition.

Comment: Thanks again, probably I didn't make my problem clear to you.
I just want to call some exe file after welcome patch UI, so my user could install the driver first before install my application.

Comment: Windows Installer is transaction based.  What you propose violates best practices because it's prior to the transaction.